# Having trouble populating an array of UUID's into their referenced type

Tags: reference, sequelize.js, associations, sequelize-typescript

Using 'sequelize-typescript' I want to populate the membersId with the Users connected to each UUID in the array. Also I'm not sure if the One-to-Many association I made between the two tables is correct. My understanding is that every chat has one owner which is a User and a User has many chats. But at the same time because chats have members they will also have access to the chat. So shouldn't it then be a Many-to-Many relationship? Confused as to how this works. Thank you.

The Chat Model

```
@Table({
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true
})
class Chat extends Model {
    @Column({
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
    })
    declare id: string;
    @Column({
        type: DataType.JSONB,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
            atleastTwoMembers(members: string[]) {
                if (Array.isArray(members) && !(members.length >= 2)) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid Member Count!');
                }
                if (!Array.isArray(members)) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid Member Count!');
                }
            }
        },
        defaultValue: []
    })
    declare membersId: User[];
    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    })
    declare chatOwnerId: string;
    @BelongsTo(() => User)
    declare chatOwner: User;
    declare chatOwner: User;
    @CreatedAt
    declare createdAt: Date;
    @UpdatedAt
    declare updatedAt: Date;
}

export default Chat;
```

And then I have a User Model

```
@Table({
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true
})
class User extends Model {
    @Column({
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
    })
    declare id: string;
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    })
    declare name: string;
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
            isEmail: true
        }
    })
    declare email: string;
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    })
    declare password: string;
    @HasMany(() => Chat)
    declare allChats: Chat[];
    declare 
    @CreatedAt
    declare createdAt: Date;
    @UpdatedAt
    declare updatedAt: Date;
}

export default User;
```

I am using pg as the database.